# If Match found in Column, move rows together

Tags: excel, vba

I'm Trying to come up with a simple macro that loops through a range. If a duplicate value is found in 'Column A', it will move the entire duplicate row below the original.

So,

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 29 |
| 3 | 86 |
| 6 | ff |
| 1 | 348 |
| 4 | dd |

Will Become

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 29 |
| 1 | 348 |
| 3 | 86 |
| 6 | ff |
| 4 | dd |

---

I've been toying with this code

```
Sub move()

        Worksheets("1").Activate
            Range("A2:A999").Select
            Selection.Sort Key1:=Range("A11"), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlGuess, _
                OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, _
                DataOption1:=xlSortNormal
End If
```

But have hit a well, any input appreciated.

Comment: Side note: please stop using the "macros" tag for VBA questions. Thank you.

Comment: Does this require VBA? What about a simple formula: `=SORTBY(A2:B6,MATCH(A2:A6,UNIQUE(A2:A6),0))`

Comment: ^^^^^ Or just sorting the range

Comment: @JvDV VBA would be nice as this is just a simplified step in a much larger process

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad unfortunately need vba, I could ust throw in a macro that sorts A-Z, but need to preserve the order.

Comment: "...need to preserve the order" ??? If you sort, the order is changed. You can [sort using VBA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.sort)